# What to do after cross-validation

Tags: validation, cross-validation, hyperparameters, train-test-split

I've read that once I've tuned my hyperparameters using k-fold cross-validation (on the training set), I should train my model on the entire training set and then evaluate my model on the test set.

However, doesn't this again introduce the problem that cross-validation is trying to solve, which is that the testing set may not be representative of the entire dataset?

Answer (score 1):

One (crude) way to think about a training score is as a measurement of the model's ability to *memorize* data.  But for predictive modeling, what we actually want to know is the model's ability to *generalize* to new data.  This is why we train on one set of data and evaluate on a held-out set of data.

Cross-validation can be used for two purposes.

The first is to get an idea of the performance of the model building process, given fixed preprocessing and hyperparameters, under conditions of limited data.  If we had a ton of data, we could just split it into training and evaluation sets, using the first to train the model and the second to evaluate the model.  But often we have limited data, and the problem is we want that data to both inform the model during training so that it can sufficiently learn the phenomenon we are modeling, but we also want to use that data to evaluate the model on held-out data.  Cross-validation is a way to increase the amount of training and evaluation data available to us, without data leaking from the training to evaluation tasks.

A second use of cross-validation is to tune hyperparameters (and/or preprocessing) of the model pipeline.  This is actually just a repeated application of the first use, but it is (in problems where time permits) a popular use of cv, and it might be worth additional description.  In this task, we have a sequence of hyperparameters that we would like to evaluate to see which ones leads to the best model.  If we just looked at the training score, we would likely end up with an overly complex model that "memorizes" the data -- a condition called overfitting the training data.  So we use held-out data to choose the best hyperparameters, and cross-validation is way to get this "score on held-out data".

If we are just considering the first use case, I think your intuition is right.  We cut out some data for the test set and thus limited our ability to train and/or validate.  If we had instead used that data as part of the input into cross-validation, we would have more data to work with.  The test set does offer some extra safety here, in that because we just trained an entirely new model (using all the training data), we have never checked its performance; and a test set can do that.  But if the data is limited, maybe the cross-validation score was a good enough (maybe even better) estimate.  One useful thing to do is to check the variance in the performance of the models fit during cv.

When we consider the second use of cross-validation, that of hyperparameter selection, things get a little more complicated.  When performing hyperparameter tuning (e.g. via random search) we are opening ourselves up to the risk of *overhyping* ("winners curse", "multiple induction problem", "multi-hypothesis testing problem").  That is, just as using the training score can cause us to overfit the training data, using validation score can cause us to overfit the validation data: we might end up picking the hyperparameters that happen to work well on the validation data and don't capture true information about the underlying phenomenon being modeled.
This is where a test set can be informative. It wasn't used to tune the hyperparameters, so your model building process can't have overfit to it.  If the validation score and the test score differ a lot, there might be cause for concern.
Secondly, ideally a test score is used once to estimate how well your deployed model will perform, and that's it.  However in practice I suspect that this ideal is often violated due to limited data.  But take note that as soon as you start to take action to tweak your model building process based on the test score, that is a form of information leakage, and the test score becomes less reliable estimate of the true generalization performance.

One way to deal with this problem of limited data to both train, tune, and evaluate the model building process is to do *nested cross-validation*.  Similar to how cross-validation helps us use a training set for both training and evaluation, nested cv helps us train, validate, and test.  But it can take a lot of resources.